# Alguien sabe como puedo añadir una funcion a un ciclo en python?

Tags: python, bucles

estaba pensando y me surgio la duda de si tengo un ciclo for de la siguiente manera:

```
for i in range(11):
```

recorrerá el ciclo desde 0 hasta 10 sin hacer nada, pero al mismo tiempo defino una función

```
def puntual(number1,number2):
    a = number1*(i-number2)
    return a
```

la cual tomara el valor de i en el ciclo. Si quiero añadir la función puntal(5,2) sin tener que escribirla directamente en el ciclo saben como se podría realizar esto?

Para hacerme entender mejor, le pido un numero a el usuario si es 1 que añada la función al ciclo, si es otro número que solo haga el ciclo sin nada dentro

Alguien tiene idea de como realizar esto?

Comment: Creo que serviria un `if` con eso bastaría `if num1 ==1: puntual(num1,num2)`

Answer (score 0):

a ver si entiendo. Queres que la funcion utilice la variable i del ciclo y solo se ejecute si el numero dado por el usuario es 1?

Podes agregar i como parametro pedido por la funcion y pasarlo despues de un if asi

```
def puntual(num1,num2,i):
     a = number1*(i-number2)
     return a

numero = input("Inserte un número:")

for i in range(11):
    if numero == '1':
        puntual(5,2,i)
```

de esta forma se imprime por pantalla

> Inserte un número:1
> -10
> -5 0 5 10 15 20 25 30 35 40